# FreePascal - How can I copy a file from one location and paste it in another?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am attempting to get a program to paste a copy of itself in the windows start-up folder. I have only been able to find the Lazarus function included in `FileUtils`, `CopyFile()` but as I'm not using Lazarus this solution doesn't work for me. is there any other way that I can do this in FreePascal? all other things related to files that I can find for FreePascal are referring to text files or the `File` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may copy one file to another with the oldschool `File` type and routines:

```pascal
function CopyFile(const SrcFileName, DstFileName: AnsiString): Boolean;
var
  Src, Dst: File;
  Buf: array of Byte;
  ReadBytes: Int64;
begin
  Assign(Src, SrcFileName);
{$PUSH}{$I-}
  Reset(Src, 1);
{$POP}
  if IOResult <> 0 then
    Exit(False);

  Assign(Dst, DstFileName);
{$PUSH}{$I-}
  Rewrite(Dst, 1);
{$POP}
  if IOResult <> 0 then begin
    Close(Src);
    Exit(False);
  end;

  SetLength(Buf, 64 * 1024 * 1024);
  while not Eof(Src) do begin
{$PUSH}{$I-}
    BlockRead(Src, Buf[0], Length(Buf), ReadBytes);
{$POP}
    if IOResult <> 0 then begin
      Close(Src);
      Close(Dst);
      Exit(False);
    end;

{$PUSH}{$I-}
    BlockWrite(Dst, Buf[0], ReadBytes);
{$POP}
    if IOResult <> 0 then begin
      Close(Src);
      Close(Dst);
      Exit(False);
    end;
  end;

  Close(Src);
  Close(Dst);
  Exit(True);
end;

begin
  if not CopyFile('a.txt', 'b.txt') then
    Halt(1);
end.
```